# Need assistance with my support ticket system

Tags: php

Okay so i am currently trying to create a support ticket system, i have everything setup but        the ticket status checker. 
    This is how the database works:
    ticknum = random generated number given to client once ticket is created
    tickid = auto incremented id, has no real use
    status = 0 or 1 0=unanswered 1=answered
how do i make a little text field where they can check the ticket status just by typing in   there ticket number?
here's what i have so far for code(it doesnt work):

Here is a link to the code:     http://pastebin.com/iX63YWRH

Please assist me with this, all i'm getting from it is a blank white page.

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` in that last if condition. Turn on error reporting in the future.

Comment: oops lol didnt see that. it works now! :D Thanks you soooo much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing } in that last if condition. Turn on error reporting in the future. – Mike B Apr 8 at 2:30